# Can Jackson parse CSV files in which different rows have different schema?

Tags: java, parsing, csv, jackson

Is it possible to *efficiently* parse a CSV file using the Jackson `jackson-dataformat-csv` library (`CsvSchema`, `CsvMapper`, etc.) *when different rows of that file have different schema*?

I emphasize *efficiently* because I have very large files (>100,000,000 rows) to parse and the application is performance sensitive. If a new `Object`/`String` is instantiated for every column in every row the GC will disown me. I want primitives whenever possible, e.g., `31` to be returned as `int`.

If so, what is the recommended approach?

FYI, the file schema is like this: `ROW_TYPE|...`. That is, the first column of every row denotes the column type and for a given column type the schema is always the same. Then the rest of the columns differ between rows, depending on their column type. E.g.:

```
1|"text1a"|2|3|4|true|"text2a"
2|3|"text"
1|"text1b"|5|6|7|false|"text2b"
```

At the moment I use the `neo4j-csv` library.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-csv</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

It is extremely performant and creates very little garbage. Also, it supports reading entries column by column, and for the type to be specified at every read - more involved, but more flexible. For reference, the usage is something like this:

```
// do once per file
CharSeeker charSeeker = new BufferedCharSeeker(...), bufferSize);
int columnDelimiter = '|';
Extractors extractors = new Extractors();
Mark mark = new Mark();

// do repeatedly while parsing
charSeeker.seek(mark, columnDelimiters))
int eventType = charSeeker.extract(mark, extractors.int_()).intValue();

switch (eventType) {
    case 1: // parse row type 1
            break;
    case 2: // parse row type 2
            break;
...
...
}
```

The reason I'm considering switching is I'd like to cut down on project dependencies and, as I already use Jackson for JSON, it makes sense to use it for CSV (performance/features pending).

Answer (score 1):

Although Jackson does not have automated support for switching between `CsvSchema`s on per-row basis (which would suggest you'd need to do two-phase processing; first read or bind as `String[]`, then use `ObjectMapper.convertValue()`), it might be possible to use existing support for polymorphic deserialization. This would rely on some commonality on column naming, so I don't know if it is realistic or not.

Assuming it'd work, you would need a base class that has property that matches logical name of first column to use; and then subtypes with similarly matching property names.
You would use `@JsonTypeInfo` on base class, and use 'name' as type id; and either use `@JsonTypeName` on sub-classes, or refer from base class using `@JsonSubTypes` annotations.
That is, use the usual Jackson configuration.

If this does not work, two-phase processing may not be a bad choice. It would result in all cell values being read as distinct objects, but as long as they are not retained (that is, you only keep one rows full of data in memory), short-term garbage usually is not that problematic for GC (long-term garbage is the expensive kind).

Comment: thanks @StaxMan, but I'm not sure this is suitable. using the `CharSeeker` parser I'm using now I do row-dependent parsing in 1 phase. I compared this approach with with regex split(), i.e. return an array of strings and then parse those strings. the amount of garbage generated was ~100x higher. 1 string for every column of every + a string[] + whatever strings are parsed to. that resulted in about 6x worse performance and unpredictable GC behavior - when you're generating >>100,000,000 objects at >>1,000,000 objects/second the GC needs to do something with them, even if they're short lived

Comment: Regex may have significantly higher overhead however. But I guess what I'd simply suggest is checking how fast/slow basic reading as `String[]` per row is. Based on benchmarking I have done CSV backend does not appear to have unreasonable overhead compared to JSON, which is why I would be surprised to see anything more than factor of 2x difference.

Comment: Also: I absolutely would NOT build a big array of rows, retain that -- this is what I mean by using streaming. If you retain all rows, Strings are bound to end up in OldGen for expensive GCs. So that could quite easily explain the difference. Jackson always reads things in incremental fashion (chunk by chunk) so memory retention is nominal.

Comment: when you write "factor of 2x difference" which two things are you comparing?

Comment: "building a big array of rows" is definitely not what I'm doing. I'm streaming. however given that `MappingIterator.nextValue()` returns a *new* thing on every call, there is a bunch of object allocation going on. even short lived objects need to be collected, and collection is not free. moreover, from benchmarking & profiling I've found the heap grows very quickly (with garbage, unused objects) when I'm parsing large files at high speeds. minimizing allocation minimizes GC, that's what I want.

Comment: Ok right. It's just that for sake of comparison you mentioned something that sounded like accumulation every row, and would explain 6x performance difference. FWIW, using `CsvParser` (or just methods from `JsonParser`) will avoid allocation of `String[]`, and some of other state. It won't eliminate allocation of per-cell value Strings at this point. In future it is possibly to avoid that for number/boolean cells, but that is not implemented yet.
Should not actually be terribly difficult to implemented (planned to originally), just hasn't been high priority.

Comment: looking forward to that addition, and to some way of being able to implement per-row schema selection! :) in case it interests you, here's the neo4j-csv code:
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/master/community/csv/src/main/java/org/neo4j/csv/reader

Comment: Thanks! Always interesting to see high-performance implementations, various ways to solve similar problems.